# Change Emacs window appearance when it loses focus

Tags: linux, emacs, lisp, elisp, dot-emacs

When I program I use two screens with Emacs on both with two buffers split in each window totaling 4 open source files on screen at any one time.

I switch between buffers with `C-x b` and between Windows with `Alt-TAB`. I change the appearance of buffers when I switch between them by defining different faces for `mode-line` and `mode-line-inactive`. But how do I inactivate a buffer when I switch from the Emacs window completely to another Emacs window via `Alt-TAB`?

It's probably also relevant that I'm using Emacs 23.2.1 on Ubuntu 11.04 with Gnome 2.32.1.

PS: The question [How to automatically save files on lose focus in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1230245/627517) is after a different goal but with the same original event of "window losing focus".

Comment: First to get the terms straight: A buffer contains a file, a window displays a buffer and a window is displayed by a frame. With Alt-Tab you switch frames. That said: As far as I can tell you can't deselect a window to get your behavior for free.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I was slightly misusing terms. I suppose I was using "window" to mean either window or frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may depend on your window manager and how it manages multiple windows, or frames, in emacs parlance. The code below works like a champ in fvwm but not always in gnome.

I map a keystroke, C-o, to go between frames, this helps when you want to go to the other frame but an alt-tab would take you through a number of superfluous apps on the way.

If you're running a single instance of emacs with two frames you could use something like the following:

```
(defun pgr-previous-frame ()
  "go to the previous frame"
  (interactive)
  (pgr-switch-frame (previous-frame)))

(defun pgr-next-frame ()
  "go to the next frame"
  (interactive)
  (pgr-switch-frame (next-frame)))

(defun pgr-switch-frame (frame)
  "go to the specified frame and raise it"
  ;; reset the frame properties here
  (select-frame frame)     
  (raise-frame frame)
  ;;change the display in some manner here
  )
```

You could also try adding some advice to raise-frame and lower-frame haven't tried it but it's worth a try.

Comment: Also, FrameMove ( http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameMove ) combines with WindMove (built-in) to create a wonderfully-intuitive way of navigating between windows/frames in Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

In Emacs 24.4 and later, you can use `focus-in-hook` and `focus-out-hook`.  This piece of code seems to work, such that the active window of an inactive frame has the same colour as an inactive window:

```
(defvar my-mode-line-active-background "gray75")
(defvar my-mode-line-inactive-background "gray40")

(defun my-unhighlight-mode-line ()
  (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
                      :background my-mode-line-inactive-background))

(add-hook 'focus-out-hook 'my-unhighlight-mode-line)

(defun my-highlight-mode-line ()
  (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
                      :background my-mode-line-active-background))

(add-hook 'focus-in-hook 'my-highlight-mode-line)
```

Answer (score 2):

I really liked @logoscia answer, which allowed me to do this more generic version.  It uses the `mode-line-inactive` face when no focus.

```
(add-hook 'focus-out-hook
      (lambda ()
        (copy-face 'mode-line '--mode-line-backup)
        (copy-face 'mode-line-inactive 'mode-line)))
(add-hook 'focus-in-hook
      (lambda ()
        (copy-face '--mode-line-backup 'mode-line)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be done only with Emacs, but a possible alternative is running [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) in a shell script which perodically checks which window has the focus and if there is a change then it lets Emacs know via [emacsclient](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) which can send lisp code to a running Emacs for evaluation:

> `-e'`--eval'
>        Tell Emacs to evaluate some Emacs Lisp code, instead of visiting
>        some files.  When this option is given, the arguments to
>        `emacsclient' are interpreted as a list of expressions to
>        evaluate, *not* as a list of files to visit.

Comment: Interesting solution but I would like the focus event to update the window appearance immediately which would require `wmctrl` to check which windows has the focus at an overwhelmingly high rate. I wonder if I can instead catch "change of focus" events.

Comment: The shell script was only a simple example. There is probably a way to subscribe to window change events in X, so you could write a separate small program which subscribes to these events and notifies emacs when it's called back by X.